# Rails: created user model and signed up but cannot log in after pull to new directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi all my first question here, I'm working on blog functionality where I created one login for myself using has_secure_password.  This involved a user model and a sessions model.  I got it set up to the point where I have certain links/post actions that are only available to me when logged in.

My problem is when I pull the project from the git repository to a new directory just to test it out, nothing happens when I go to sign in, it just loads the form again and my actions aren't available.  It just doesn't know that there is a user there.  I'm not sure if this is some sort of security feature, but I was hoping to be set up locally and then using the login when I eventually push to heroku.

below is some code (from https://github.com/mostlybadfly/recetera)
This is my users controller (removed some methods to prevent creating of account)

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end 

private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

end
```

This is my sessions controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      flash[:success] = "Successfully Logged in"
      redirect_to users_path
    else
      flash.now[:warning] = "Invalid email or password"
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    flash[:info] = "Logged out!"
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

This is the sessions new view:

```
<h2>Sign in</h2>
<div class="row">
  <div>
  <%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path, html: { class: "form-horizontal" }) do |f| %>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :email, class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
      <div class="col-sm-6"><%= f.text_field :email %></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :password, class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
      <div class="col-sm-6"><%= f.password_field :password %></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-6"><%= f.submit "Sign In", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %></div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">

</div>
```

Users model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }

  validates :name, presence: true

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true,
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }

  has_secure_password
end
```

I appreciate the help!

Comment: What do you mean by "when I pull the project to a new directory just to test it out". A gist of you logs would also help

Comment: I meant that when I pull from the git repository.  I'll have to grab that information this afternoon and share.

Comment: Do you have anywhere where you display the flash messages?

Comment: @Baloo I THOUGHT I had it in application.html.erb ,so i'll have to fix that.

Comment: what does your User model look like? also in your controller at the start of the create method try doing a puts params.to_yaml to see what is in the params at that point? my guess is that it is empty...

Comment: @user3334690 , I'll have to check it out. I assumed it had something to do with using resources :sessions, tu not sure if that makes too much sense.  It is odd, it works in my local directly but not on my laptop. I was trying to create a simple login at first so I can update some posts on my progress and realized I got in way over my head!

Comment: @mostlybadfly So do you get a flash message now?  If so what does it say

Comment: well if I had to guess, params isn't looking like what you are expecting, which is probably a result of using :session in your form_for like you do... I would replace :session in the form_for with User.new... keep in mind that will change how you get stuff from the params in the create though...

Comment: @user3334690 , I have added the users model to the original post. I'll report back this afternoon with the results from the controller. My confusion with creating form_for User.new would be that i'm just trying to login with the user I thought I already created.  I don't need to make new users.

Comment: well the new user wouldn't be created until you saved it, the real purpose of using the User.new in the form_for is for structure... my guess as to what is going on is that :session doesn't have :email or :password... unlike other things, however, :session doesn't really throw no method exceptions... so your params hash is probably empty, or all the keys are nil...  using User.new would just be practical because it already has the email and password, the proper thing to do might be to use [form_tags](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html), but they are a pain

Comment: @user3334690 i'll try those things out and report back.  I appreciate the help!

Comment: @Baloo I get invalid email or password

Comment: @user3334690 no output from that puts. I think it got way to convoluted. I'm going to reconsider and get more familiar with this before proceeding.  thank you for your efforts :)

Comment: ok, well I went ahead and posted an answer illustrating a bit of what I was suggesting... as far as I can tell, you're very close to having it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is most likely with the use of :session in the form_for in your view.  My guess is that since email and password don't exist for :session they do not end up in your params.  Personally, I would create a new instance of the User for the form_for since that is who is logging in and probably won't mean changing your form much

```
<h2>Sign in</h2>
<div class="row">
  <div>
  <%= form_for(User.new, url: sessions_path, html: { class: "form-horizontal" }) do |f| %>

    <div class="form-group">
      ...
    </div>
  <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your params hash will look differently now though, since it will be an instance of User that is being used to create it.  As a result, your controller should now look more like:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:user][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:user][:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      flash[:success] = "Successfully Logged in"
      redirect_to users_path
    else
      flash.now[:warning] = "Invalid email or password"
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    flash[:info] = "Logged out!"
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

Alternatively, form tags might be better for this situation. Using them would make your view look something like:

```
<h2>Sign in</h2>
<div class="row">
  <div>
  <%= form_tag(sessions_path, html: { class: "form-horizontal" }) do %>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-6"><%= text_field_tag "email" %></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-6"><%= text_field_tag "password" %></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-6"><%= submit_tag "Sign In", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %></div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your controller would then change to look something like:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      flash[:success] = "Successfully Logged in"
      redirect_to users_path
    else
      flash.now[:warning] = "Invalid email or password"
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    flash[:info] = "Logged out!"
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

Personally, I would probably recommend the [form tags](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) in this situation.

Also, I don't recommend it, but you might be able to get it to work with what you have by changing the new in your controller to look like:

```
def new
  session[:email] = ""
  session[:password] = ""
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it put me in the spot where I needed to be.